# Почему функции которые содержат циклы, рекурсию или вызываются по указателю, плохо подвержены встраиванию (inline)

Tags: c++, функции, циклы, рекурсия, inline

Почему функции которые содержат циклы, рекурсию или вызываются по указателю, плохо подвержены встраиванию (inline)

Comment: инлайн - по сути (упрощённо) - вместо функции сразу пишется её код. При этом на инлайн функцию нельзя создать указатель. А нет указателя - нельзя делать рекурсию. Циклы можно инлайнить, но _обычно_ компилятор их распутывает (делает условно 10 итераций цикла и двигает итератор на 10 позиций), поэтому при инлайне столько место займёт что нецелесообразно. А вообще inline - костыль и умный комплятор сам принимает решение

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Вопрос построен на терминологической путанице. Встраивание вызовов функции - это не свойство самой функции, а всегда именно свойство *индивидуального вызова функции*. Свойства самой функции, разумеется, играют роль в принятии решения о том, будет ли конкретный вызов встроен, но все равно в общем случае это решение принимается для каждого отдельного вызова индивидуально. Одни *вызовы* функции могут оказаться встроены, в то время как другие *вызовы* той же функции могут оказаться не встроены. Даже аргументы функции, указанные в конкретном вызове, могут влиять на решение о том, встраивать ли этот конкретный вызов.

- Утверждение о том, что вызовы функций с циклами не встраиваются, относится к категории "это было давно и неправда".

  Каждый компилятор реализует какой-то набор эвристических критериев, который дает ему возможность принимать общие решения о том, заслуживают ли вызовы данной функции встраивания. В каком-то из старинных компиляторов этот эвристический критерий также включал проверку тела функции на наличие циклов (Borland или что-то в этом роде).

  На самом деле циклы не представляют из себя никаких преград для встраивания. Мне не известны никакие современные реализации, которые бы отказывались встраивать вызовы функций с циклами внутри.
- Утверждение о том, что функции, которые вызываются через указатель, не встраиваются - это как раз яркий пример того терминологической путаницы, о которой я писал выше. Это *вызовы*, выполненные через указатель, в общем случае не встраиваются. В то же время *вызовы* той же самой функции, выполненные напрямую, могут прекрасно встраиваться.

  Почему в общем случае невозможно встроить вызов, сделанный через указатель, очевидно: потому что на стадии компиляции не ясно, какая функция будет вызываться. Однако если компилятор в состоянии сообразить на стадии компиляции, какая функция будет вызвана через указатель, он без проблем встроит и такой вызов.

  Классический часто задаваемый вопрос, основанный на данной терминологической путанице - вопрос о встраивании вызовов виртуальных методов классов. Они ведь вызываются "через указатель" и значит не могут быть встроены, правда? Не правда. Во-первых, сам пользователь может выполнить вызов виртуального метода напрямую, без использования виртуального механизма. Во-вторых, в огромном количестве контекстов сам компилятор в состоянии сообразить, какой конкретный метод вызывается в данном вызове и, соответственно, встроить этот вызов.
- Вызовы рекурсивных функций тоже могут встраиваться. Если компилятор на стадии компиляции в состоянии оценить максимальную глубину рекурсии, то он может встроить эти вызовы ("развернуть рекурсию") на всю глубину. Если компилятор не в состоянии выполнить такой оценки, то он может встроить рекурсивные вызовы до определенной фиксированной глубины, после чего выполнить обычный рекурсивный вызов. Встраивание вызовов рекурсивных функции в этом отношении во многом аналогично развертке циклов.

Одной из простейших и наиболее очевидных ситуаций целесообразности встраивания вызова функции является, например, ситуация, когда заведомо известно, что некоторая функция вызывается в программе ровно один раз (в *пространственном* смысле, т.е. исходный код программы содержит ровно одно место с ее вызовом). Такой функции нет никакого смысла существовать в виде отдельной функции, независимо от того, как "тяжела" эта функция. (С этим идет ряд побочных оговорок, но к данной теме они не относятся.) Например, если функция имеет внутреннее связывание и вызывается в своей единице трансляции ровно один раз, то современные компиляторы встроят этот вызов независимо от каких-либо иных критериев. В компиляторе GCC за это отвечает опция `-finline-functions-called-once`, которая включается уже в режиме `-O1`.

В качестве другого примера, в компиляторе MSVC++ есть `#pragma`-параметры `inline_recursion` и `inline_depth`, которые управляют встраиванием рекурсивных функций и глубиной развертки рекурсии.

Answer (score 12):

Ну, с рекурсией понятно - если она не преобразована компилятором в цикл, то что получится? встраиваем код, на месте ее вызова опять встраиваем код, в котором на месте вызова... Сколько раз код встраивать? :)

С вызовом по указателю - опять же: если встроена, то функция не имеет четкого пролога-эпилога, и не может быть вызвана по адресу - так что при вызове через указатель должен иметься не встроенный экземпляр функции как минимум - чтобы было, что вызывать.

В самом месте вызова через указатель встроить ничего нельзя - так как встраивает компилятор, а во время компиляции значение указателя неизвестно.

А про циклы - мне кажется, тут вы что-то напутали. Функция с циклом внутри вполне встраиваема - если, конечно, это имеет смысл :) Если вы имеете в виду, что сам цикл раскручивается - то опять же, это делается, но со своими ограничениями - например, компилятор может не знать, сколько реально итераций будет сделано - так как ему цикл разворачивать?..

Comment: про циклы не я сказал а Мейерс - "Большинство  компиляторов  отвергают  встраивание  функций,  которые представляются  слишком  сложными  (например,  содержат  циклы  или  рекурсию),  и  за исключением  наиболее  тривиальных  случаев,  вызов  виртуальной функции  отменяет встраивание." все тоже правило 30 про inline функции

Comment: `с рекурсией понятно - если она не преобразована компилятором в цикл, то что получится? ` - получиться `goto` :)

Comment: @NewView а состояние регистров тоже через goto восстанавливать?...

Comment: я бы сказал что inline вообще это не часть стандарта и как компилятор захочет - так и будет. может вообще `#define inline` сделать

Comment: Зависит от кода, но `eax` переписать проблем не вижу, или же целиком `popa/popd`. Но в любом случае это дело компилятора, а он в этом плане явно умнее нас :)

Comment: @NewView Мы говорим о рекурсии в общем случае, а не об оконечной (хвостовой)...

Comment: @Harry, Ну я просто к слову заметил, так то все правильно в плане ответа :)

Comment: @pavel: Это совершенно не верно. В отношении самой функции (и, начиная с C++17, переменных) ключевое слово `inline` не имеет никакого отношения к встраиванию, а имеет прямое отношение к Правилу Одного Определения (ODR). Эффект `inline` для ODR огромен, однозначен и проигнорирован быть никак не может. Ни о каком `#define inline` не может быть и речи.